# send an email based on smtp.gmail.com from magento

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, phpstorm

I don't have any mail servers.

So how to configure the mail settings`(settings->configuration->advanced->system->Mail sending settings)` in magento admin panel using smtp.gmail.com

and how to send an email based on that settings ?

Comment: code over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558156/magento-how-enable-smtp-server-authentication-and-secure-transport#comment31321014_11558156 that can be used as a starting point to build your own module to use secured SMTP transport.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to configure magento to use something else for sending mails than the builtin `mail()`, but ASchroder implemented something for this:

[Magento SMTP Pro Extension](https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension)